Analytic solution to Fokker-Planck PDE initial boundary value problem.
I am interested in the evolution of the probability density of a mean-reverting process, specifically an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. While there are several examples on Stack Exchange of solutions to the Fokker-Planck PDE, I haven't found any that consider absorbing boundaries.
In particular, I'm interested in the closed-form solution to the following partial differential equation (PDE):
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(x,t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\theta(\mu-x)p(x,t)\right] + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p(x,t),
$$
where $ p(x,t) $ is the probability density function, $ \theta $ is the rate of mean reversion, and $ \mu $ is the mean the process reverts to.
I am considering the interval $ \Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < x < \eta \} $ with the boundary conditions: $p(0,t) = p(\eta,t) = 0$
Further, I assume a uniform initial condition:
$$
p(x,0) = \frac{1}{\eta} \mathbf{1}_{(0,\eta)}(x)$$
Such that boundary and initial conditions agree at $ x=0 $ and $ x=\eta $.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit: $\mu \in (0,\eta)$, and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

Is $\mu\in(0,\eta)$? Is $\theta$ a constant, or a function of $\mu-x$? What are the definitions of mean reversion speed and mean reversion level?

Yes, those are the correct assumptions. I think 'rate of mean reversion' and the 'mean the process reverts too' might be better ways to put those phrases

$\theta$ is a constant, I've edited the question with your clarifications. Thank you

No magic bullet here. Probably you can try separation of variables. You'll get an infinite sum of modes multiplied by exponentials in time. There will be some eigenfunctions and eigenvalues given by a (probably transcendental) secular equation. You can read similar solutions in the 1950s books where people solve the heat equation for different conditions.

Book recommendations are welcome, thank you !
